# Replace a subString in an std::string but not all of them using C++

Tags: c++, string, algorithm, replace, c++14

I'm new to C++, I know that my post can be found duplicate with other posts but what I want to do is that to replace a substring in a string but not all of them.

This is my find and replaces substring function, it's worked like the other replace function:

```
void findAndReplaceAll(std::string& data, std::string toSearch, std::string replaceStr)
{
//Get the first occurrence
size_t pos = data.find(toSearch);

//Repeat till end is reached
while (pos != std::string::npos)
{
    //Replace this occurrence of Sub String
    data.replace(pos, toSearch.size(), replaceStr);
    //Get the next occurrence from the current position
    pos = data.find(toSearch, pos + replaceStr.size());
}
}
```

My main function:

```
int main()
{
    std::string format = "h 'o''cloch' a, zzzz";
    findAndReplaceAll(format, "h", "%h");
    return 0;
}
```

The output that I want is just to replace the first 'h' but not the second 'h' one.

```
"%h 'o''cloch' a,zzzz";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a separate function that replaces only one found string.

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

bool findAndReplace( std::string &data, 
                     const std::string &toSearch, 
                     const std::string &replaceStr,
                     std::string::size_type pos = 0 )
{
    bool success = pos < data.size();

    if ( success )
    {
        success = ( pos = data.find( toSearch, pos ) ) != std::string::npos;

        if ( success )
        {
            data.replace( pos, toSearch.size(), replaceStr );
        }
    }

    return success;
}                     

int main() 
{
    std::string format = "h 'o''cloch' a, zzzz";

    findAndReplace( format, "h", "%h" );

    std::cout << "\"" << format << "\"\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
"%h 'o''cloch' a, zzzz"
```

Comment: That's great, your program did the job. But what about the input string is `std::string format = "hh 'o''cloch' a, zzzz";` What I want is to replace the substring which is not inside each pair of single quote, anything outside will be replaced.

Comment: @NguyễnĐứcTâm It is another problem and another question.:)

Comment: Yes, it is because I just figured it out :(.

Comment: Can you help me with that too??

Comment: @NguyễnĐứcTâm I think it can be done using regular expressions. In any case you should close the question selecting the useful answer and ask a new question with new requirements.

Answer (score 2):

You can add an argument to your function that tells after how many characters you need to stop replacing substrings.

The function prototype would look something like this: `void findAndReplaceAll(std::string& data, std::string toSearch, std::string replaceStr, int stopAfterXCharacters)`.

You would then need to change your `while` loop to stop when that certain amount of characters has been read.

Alternatively, you could have a function that only replaces a certain amount of substrings, and in your case your function would return if one substring has been changed.